# In evil-mode how to just press J to move the cursor down 3 lines

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

When in evil-mode, I can make the cursor go down 3 lines by command '*C-u 3 M-x evil-next-line*' , but how can I make the cursor go down 3 lines by just pressing J?

Comment: `3j` works for me.  Or do you want `j` to *always* move in increments of 3?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want capital j to achieve the function of 3j，can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Short answer**

Add this to your `.emacs` file:

```
(evil-define-motion evil-next-line-3 (count)
  "Move the cursor 3 * COUNT lines down."
  :type line
  (let (line-move-visual)
    (evil-line-move (* 3 (or count 1)))))
```

Note that `J` is currently bound to `evil-join`.

If you are ok to rebind it, just add:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "J" 'evil-next-line-3)
```

Now, to join lines, you may either type `M-x` `evil-join` `RET` or bind something else to `evil-join` (see below).

Note that, if you type `2J`, you'll move twice 3 lines down, which is more or less 6 lines down... and `C-u` `J` will move 4*3 = 12 lines down.

**2. Not so short answer (what I actually did)**

I never used `evil-mode`... so I tried to add this package and enabled the `evil-mode` (which is ok for me since I know the main `vi` commands and I know how to disable it with `C--` `M-x` `evil-mode` `RET`).

When `evil-mode` is enabled and I type `C-h` `k` `J`, the Help buffer says:

```
J runs the command evil-join (found in evil-normal-state-map), 
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to J.

(evil-join BEG END)

Join the selected lines.
```

Then I typed `C-h` `k` `j`, clicked the `evil-commands.el` link from the Help buffer and copied and adapted the definition of the `evil-next-line` function to the `evil-next-line-3` function and bound it to `J`.

In case you want to go back to the previous binding of `J` (or want to bind it to something else), you can evaluate something like:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "J" 'evil-join)
```